# Podspec dependency on OpenSSL

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, static-libraries, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a Pod that depends on OpenSSL-Universal. I've had some trouble, so for reference, I looked for other pods that had such a dependency, and found CoreBitcoin: https://github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin

There, in CoreBitcoin.podspec, it clearly says:

```
s.dependency 'OpenSSL-Universal', '1.0.1.j-2'
```

Now, I tried including the same dependency too, went to the auto-generated example folder, and ran pod install. Here's what my auto-generated Podfile looks like, except for the project name replacements and the OpenSSL dependency:

```
#
# Be sure to run `pod lib lint <ProjectName>.podspec' to ensure this is a
# valid spec before submitting.
#
# Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "<ProjectName>"
  s.version          = "0.1.0"
  s.summary          = "A short description of <ProjectName>."

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!  
  s.description      = <<-DESC
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<ProjectName>"
  # s.screenshots     = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "<name>" => "<email>" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<ProjectName>.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }


  s.platform     = :ios, '8.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    '<ProjectName>' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  s.dependency 'OpenSSL-Universal', '1.0.1.j-2'
end
```

But then, when I go to pod install, I get the following error:

```
[!] The 'Pods-<ProjectName>_Example' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/Users/<name>/Developer/<ProjectName>/Example/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a and /Users/<name>/Developer/<ProjectName>/Example/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libssl.a)
```

I've been searching online, and people have been saying that such issues arise because OpenSSL-Universal is requiring static libraries. And I get that, that's not good, but I need my Pod to work with both iOS and OSX and somehow, CoreBitcoin has managed to use that dependency, which means it is possible. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I have tried setting up a completely new project that is not a Pod, but just a simple project with a dependency on CoreBitcoin. Running `pod install` yielded the same error, so I don't think that it is an issue with the Podspec. It might be an issue with the Podfile assuming that CoreBitcoin is doing nothing wrong. I tried running it both with and without `use_frameworks!`.

Comment: Are you using the `use_frameworks!` setting?

Comment: Yes, @Cristik, the Podfile in the auto-generated example does have `use_frameworks!`.

Comment: If you're not using Swift in your project, try removing the setting, and run a pod install. This will instruct CocoaPods to create static libraries for the dependent pods. If you're using Swift, then...

Comment: I'm afraid I am using Swift in my project. I should have been more explicit about that than just adding the `swift` tag.

Comment: In that case you can try adding a new ObjC target that will use the OpenSSL pod and create a facade to export the functionality to Swift. `use_frameworks!` should be configurable per target. Note that this is a suggestion, I don't know if it will work, or if you'll get rid of the initial errors.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll try it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  pod 'CoreBitcoin', :podspec => 'https://raw.github.com/oleganza/CoreBitcoin/master/CoreBitcoin.podspec'
```

This works on my personal project.
Hope it help others too.